# homotopy classes of maps from $S^3/\Gamma$ to $X$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Given a finite subgroup $\Gamma <SO(4)$ and a topological space $X$ whose $i$th homotopy group $\pi_i(X)$ are known for any $i$, is there any way to compute $[S^3/\Gamma,X]$?

Here $[S^3/\Gamma,X]$ means the homotopy classes of continuous maps $S^3/\Gamma \to X$. I was wondering if it can be expressed in terms of $\pi_i(X)$ and $\Gamma$.

Comment: You ask a lot of good questions - I can't keep up with thinking about all of them! I think you will find this difficult, and I have frequently wished I knew the answer for some special cases. (Really, you are asking to compute certain equviariant homotopy groups, with the different homotopy groups indexed by homomorphisms $\Gamma \to \pi_1 X$.) But hopefully someone will prove me wrong.